# Combining resources in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-resource

I have a RESTful API that provides me with employees and departments. In my AngularJS app, I need to know the employee and the departments the employee belongs to. I have defined two factory services for that:

```
angular.module('myApp.services', [])
    .factory('Employee', function ($resource) {
        return $resource ('/api/employees/:id', { id: '@id' });
    })
    .factory('Department', function ($resource) {
        return $resource ('/api/departments/:id', { id: '@id' });
    })
;
```

In the controller, I call:

```
$scope.employee = Employee.get({id: 'me'});
```

Next, I want to call:

```
$scope.departments = [];
angular.forEach($scope.employee.departmentIds, function (departmentId) {
    $scope.departments.push(Department.get({ id: departmentId }));
});
```

But `$scope.employee` is a promise object, so `$scope.employee.departmentIds` will only be known when the first request is completed.

I could solve it like this:

```
Employee.get({id: 'me'}).$promise.then(function (employee) {
    $scope.employee = employee;
    $scope.departments = [];
    angular.forEach(employee.departmentIds, function (departmentId) {
        $scope.departments.push(Department.get({ id: departmentId }));
    });
});
```

The problem is that I need this information in multiple controllers, and don't want to repeat this code in every controller. So my question is: is there a way to combine these two resources as a service which provides both the employee data and the data of the departments to which that employee belongs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is based on the answer of @Beterraba (but the code example in that answer is incorrect):

Service:

```
angular.module('myApp.services', [])
    .factory('SimpleEmployee', function ($resource) {
        return $resource ('/api/employees/:id', { id: '@id' });
    })
    .factory('Department', function ($resource) {
        return $resource ('/api/departments/:id', { id: '@id' });
    })
    .factory('Employee', ['SimpleEmployee', 'Department', function(SimpleEmployee, Department) {
        return {
            get: function(params) {
                return SimpleEmployee.get({id: params.id}).$promise.then(function (employee) {
                    employee.departments = [];
                    angular.forEach(employee.departmentIds, function (departmentId) {
                        employee.departments.push(Department.get({ id: departmentId }));
                    });
                    delete employee.departmentIds;
                    return employee;
                });
            }
        }
    }]);
```

Controller:

```
Employee.get({ id: 'me' }).then(function (employee) {
    $scope.employee = employee;
});
```

From AngularJS 1.2 RC3 on you need to unwrap any promise objects on the controller. I found this information [here](http://markdalgleish.com/2013/06/using-promises-in-angularjs-views/).

- [commit](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/5dc35b527b3c99f6544b8cb52e93c6510d3ac577)
- [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4158)

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like that:

```
angular.module('myApp.services', [])
    .factory('SimpleEmployee', function ($resource) {
        return $resource ('/api/employees/:id', { id: '@id' });
    })
    .factory('Department', function ($resource) {
        return $resource ('/api/departments/:id', { id: '@id' });
    })
    .factory('Employee', ['SimpleEmployee', 'Department', function(SimpleEmployee, Department) {
        return {
            get: function(params) {
                var data = SimpleEmployee.get({id: params.id}, function (employee) {
                    var obj = {
                        employee: employee,
                        departments: []
                    };                        
                    angular.forEach(employee.departmentIds, function (departmentId) {
                        obj.departments.push(Department.get({ id: departmentId }));
                    });
                    return obj;
                });
                return data;
            }
        }
    }]);
```

And you dont need to change anything in your controller.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. It only contains the SimpleEmployee object, not the Department objects.

Comment: @Korneel Sorry. I copy and paste your resource code and dont see your error. You was calling `Department.get({ departmentId: departmentId })` but defined the resource as `$resource ('/api/departments/:id', { id: '@id' });`. Edited

Comment: You should also change `var data = Employee...` to `var data = SimpleEmployee...`, but that's not the problem. The Departments resources get fetched correctly, but the object on the scope doesn't contain the departments objects, only the SimpleEmployee object. I guess I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Well, it actually does work, but I have to do it like this: `Employee.get({ id: 'me' }).then(function (data) { $scope.employee = data.employee; $scope.departments = data.departments; }`. Is there a way to provide the data to the scope without using the `then` callback?

Comment: Okay thanks, I tested that, but that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: In the newer versions of AngularJS you have to unwrap any promise objects on the controller: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/5dc35b527b3c99f6544b8cb52e93c6510d3ac577