# How to Combine factories to single factory in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

In the `service.js` file I have created two factories. Please let me know how to combine these two factories to one. So that I can import only one factory in my controller.

```
.factory('DeliveryReport', function($resource, API_URL) {
    return $resource(API_URL  + 'security/:userId/:timestamp/listOfDeliveries', {
      userId : '@userId',
      timestamp : '@timestamp'
    }, {
      update: {
        method: 'PUT'
      }
    });
  })

  .factory('GuestReport', function($resource, API_URL) {
    return $resource(API_URL  + 'security/:userId/:timestamp/listOfGuests', {
      userId : '@userId',
      timestamp : '@timestamp'
    }, {
      update: {
        method: 'PUT'
      }
    });
  })
```

Comment: You can pass one more parameter to the factory call which will be the last bit of your API url i.e listOfDeliveries or listOfGuests

Comment: hello! Dubai?? am working on Asp.Net.  . kindly change this question title :(

Comment: Report.get({
              userId : Safence_App.userId,
              timestamp : data.expectedDate,
              listOfGuests : listOfGuests
            }, data, function(success) {
                $scope.guests = success;
            },function(err) {
              console.log(err);
              $rootScope.hideLoading();
              $ionicPopup.alert({
                title: 'Error!',
                template: 'Something went wrong. Guest not registered'
              });
            });

Comment: This is my controller.. I have added one parameter in the controller as well as service. But it didn t work

Comment: Thanks guys.. I found a solution by adding      arg1 : '@arg1' in the service and passed the value in the controller like   arg1 : 'listOfGuests'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combining resources in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20289820/combining-resources-in-angularjs)